# What do I miss on this function? $f(t) = (t-1)^{s/2}-t^{s/2}+1$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, analysis, functions

I would like to know the sign  the function $f: [1,\infty)\to \Bbb R$ given by 
$$f(t) = (t-1)^{s/2}-t^{s/2}+1$$ with $0<s<1.$ Differentiating I have 
$$f(t) = \frac{s}{2}\left[(t-1)^{s/2-1}-t^{s/2-1}\right]\ge 0$$ 
indeed, $0<t-1<t$ and $-1<\frac{s}{2}-1<-\frac{1}{2}<0.$

Therefore the function $f$ is increasing and we have $ f(1) =0$

Hence I could conclude that $$ f(t)\ge 0~~~~t\ge 1. $$

> **Problem:**
>   Patently in the following I found a contradictory argument. Since 
>   $$ \lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}[(t-1)^{s/2}-t^{s/2}+1]= \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{(1-t)^{s/2}-1}{t^{s/2}}+1\\\sim \lim_{t\to 0^+}\frac{-{s/2}}{t^{s/2-1}}+1 = -\infty$$

The problem is that, according to the above result, this limit  of $f$ at infinity  limit should instead  $\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)=\infty$. Rather this give a contradiction.

Which of the following  is false ? $ f(t)\ge 0~~~~t\ge 1. $ or $\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)=-\infty$. and why ? what did I miss.

Patently I am facing the same paradox with the function $g(x) = (x+1)^{s/2}-x^{s/2}-1~~~x>0. $ where I also got $ g(x)\le 0~~~~x\le 0. $ and  $\lim_{x\to \infty} g(x)=\infty$.

Comment: How did you came up with last limit?

Comment: $1/t^{s/2-1}=t^{1-s/2}\to 0$ as $t\to 0$. That $f(t)$ is increasing does not necessarily imply $\lim_{t\to\infty}f(t)=+\infty$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it more slowly; you're doing the substitution $t=1/u$, so the limit becomes
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}
\left[
\left(\frac{1}{u}-1\right)^{s/2}-\frac{1}{u^{s/2}}+1
\right]=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\left[
1+\frac{(1-u)^{s/2}-1}{u^{s/2}}
\right]
$$
Now, using l'Hôpital,
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{(1-u)^{s/2}-1}{u^{s/2}}
=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{(s/2)(1-u)^{s/2-1}}{(s/2)u^{s/2-1}}=
\lim_{u\to0^+}(1-u)^{s/2-1}u^{1-s/2}=0
$$

Where are you making a mistake? For $0<s<1$, you have
$$
\frac{s}{2}-1<-\frac{1}{2}
$$
so your last denominator has limit infinity and the fraction has limit $0$.

Using Taylor,
$$
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{(1-u)^{s/2}-1}{u^{s/2}}=
\lim_{u\to0^+}\frac{-(s/2)u}{u^{s/2}}=
\lim_{u\to0^+}-\frac{s}{2}u^{1-s/2}=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
f(t) & = t^{s/2} \left(1-\frac{1}{t} \right)^{s/2} - t^{s/2}+1 \\
& = t^{s/2} \left[ 1 - \frac{s}{2t} + \frac{s/2(s/2-1)}{2!} \frac{1}{t^2} - ... \right] - t^{s/2}+1 \\
& = \frac{s}{2} t^{s/2 - 1} + \frac{s/2(s/2-1)}{2!} t^{s/2 -2} - ... + 1 \\
\end{align}
$

But since $0 < \frac{s}{2} < \frac{1}{2}$, all powers of $t$ in the above are strictly less than $0$, from this I think it's clear that 
$\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = 1$.

Comment: where did the minus in the second line  went to ? I mean the fiorst fact in first line should be $-s/2t^{s/2-1}$

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean? You've defined both $f(t)$ and its derivative as $f(t)$, so it's pretty unclear which function you're talking about here. From your question and other people's comments, I assumed that you wanted to disprove the statement that $\lim_{t \to \infty} f(t) = -\infty $, with $f(t)$ as you have initially defined it.

Answer (score -1):

You found the result of the limit of $f(x)$ wrong.

In infinity, we have:
$\lim_{t\to \infty} (t-1)^{c}\sim\lim_{t\to \infty} t^{c}$

So for the limit we can simplify like below:
$\lim_{t\to \infty} f(t)=\lim_{t\to \infty}[(t-1)^{s/2}-t^{s/2}+1]= \lim_{t\to \infty}[t^{s/2}-t^{s/2}+1]=1 >0$

Comment: Thanks for giving another wrong answer? You too you compute it in a wrong way. with you logic we have $2x+1=(x+1)^2-x^2 \to 0$ which is completely wrong

Comment: Dude!!! First of all, you can also compute it in Matlab or Mathematica. (I did it right now to double check and the answer was again 1). Second, for your example, $(x+1)^2 - x^2$ is $\infty - \infty$ and cannot be considered 0!

Comment: Guy's point is that this is the same mistake you have made in equating $(t-1)^c$ with $t^c$.

Comment: @MehrdadZandigohar i am just pointing out where you did wrong with elementary argument. also note all that softwares (Matlab, mathematica .....) are mankind made. I count the number of time i got wrong answer from software. excuse me if i dont trust them at 100%